# Core data cross referencing two relationships

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a data structure in Core Data like so...

User

Item

Category

User has a toMany relationship "FavouriteItems" to the Item entity.
Category also has a toMany relationship "Items" to the Item entity.

The user can select favourite items from any categories they wish.  At the moment I am listing all the items and then displaying the Category alongside.

What I'd like to do is display all the user's favouriteItems for a selected Category.

i.e. select all the Items that have a relationship with Category x and User y.

I'm currently doing this by getting all the Items through one relationship (i.e. User.favouriteItems) and then filtering the NSSet using a block predicate.

Is it possible though to do this with a simple CoreData predicate?

Hmm... thinking about it would a predicate like this work...

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"interestedUser.id = %@ AND category.id = %@", user.id, category.id];
```

And then run a fetch request on the item entity?

Would that work?

Comment: Quick update.  It doesn't like the to-many relationship used in the predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shooting pretty blind as that's an awkward scenario to set up just to answer a question but perhaps

If you are filtering an array of Items which has the correct inverse relationships set up.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN interestedUsers AND %@ IN categories", 
                                 someUser, 
                                 someCategory];
```

Basically the `Item` has many users (`interestedUsers`) so we are saying is our user in this collection.

Similarly the `Item` has many categories (`categories`) so we are saying `AND` is our chosen category in this collection.

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect with one change.  Only the interestedUsers is many-to-many, the category is one-to-many (i.e. each item only has one category).

Now I know the IN I can create the predicate.  Thanks!